# C# define an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I tried everything i could and googled about it too, but i seem to be stuck

i have an object that looks like this:

```
SubmitJob(HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.XMPUser XMPUser, string inJobTicket, string inPriority, string inTouchPointID, HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property[] inProps)
```

I defined

```
var user = new XMPieProduction.XMPUser
                    {
                        Username = "user",
                        Password = "pass"
                    };
```

the only problem i have is with this HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property[] inProps argument....

the HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property has only two string attributes (m_name and m_value),,,

I am using a webservice that gave me this structure..

I tried everything to create that inProps argument but nothing seems to work,,,

I tried:

```
HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property props = new HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property
                    {
                        m_Name = "0",
                        m_Value = "0"
                    };
```

but when i call jobId = productionWrapper.Client.SubmitJob(user, ticketId, "0", "0", props);
it will error our saying that the props argument is invalid...

I dont know how to define that Property[] argument...

any ideas ???

Comment: i hate when stupid people have nothing to do rather than down vote a serious, well formed question... Stackoverflow has too many kids online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to initialize the array *as well as the items inside it*:

```
HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property[] props = 
    new HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property []
        {
            new HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property
                {
                    m_Name = "0",
                    m_Value = "0"
                }
        };
```

or if you already have instances that are initialized outside of the array:

```
HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property prop =        
     new HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property
            {
                m_Name = "0",
                m_Value = "0"
            };

HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property[] props = 
    new HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction.Property []
        {
            prop 
        };
```

I would also recommend using `var` and `using` to reduce the length of type names:

```
using HTSignCreator.XMPieProduction;


...

var props = 
    new Property[]
        {
            new Property
                {
                    m_Name = "0",
                    m_Value = "0"
                }
        };
```